# Setup PostgreSQL 9.6 in Windows 10 x64 (BigSQL graphical installer)

Tags: postgresql, windows-10, postgresql-9.6

I'm posting this since I wasted so much time trying to figure this out. I needed a postgresql dev server and I barely can find any material for Windows 10 x64.

1. Download Postgresql (BigSQL) from postgresql website. Install using
   default options. Note down any emails, usernames, ports, and / or
   passwords.
2. Add `"C:\PostgreSQL\pg96\bin"` to environment variables. This will allow you 
   to use postgresql commands in your terminal.

When you run any postgresql commands, you may get errors similar to

> "FATAL: role "SomeUsername" does not exist"

I wasted so much time on the above error. To resolve look at the following solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open a new cmd terminal. Enter

```
psql template postgres
```

postgres should be the default username created with BigSQL

```
CREATE ROLE "SomeUsername" LOGIN SUPERUSER CREATEDB CREATEROLE REPLICATION;
```

Replace `SomeUsername` with your Windows account username. Keep everything, including the "" the same. Without the quotes, it will rename your username to its lowercase version (unexpected...). Also, I don't recommend the above attributes for a production server (ie. SUPERUSER, etc).

If successfully created, it should display

> CREATE ROLE

If you made mistakes, you can drop the role and try again

```
DROP ROLE "SomeUsername";
```

Quit using

```
\q
```